# How to check the size of a file before that the server receive it?

Tags: html, file, input, field

I have a issue on uploading files:

In order to avoid an *overloading* of the server, I would check the size of a file **before** that the **server receives** it. If I am not wrong, pressing the submit button of a form which contains a file input field (`<input type="file" name="...">`), the server first will entirely receive the file and after will check the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing that file uploads will have a Content-Length header, in which case, you can just check that at the server end and drop the connection if it's too large.

Comment: That depends on your server-side language/framework. Any decent framework will let you read the headers on an incoming request. For exploratory purposes, you can run Fiddler2 (assuming you're on Windows; Wireshark as a fall back) to inspect the packets going back and forth.